# TYPO3-Extbase Login

Tags: authentication, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I want to add a login page to my existing extension.
I followed [the tutorial on the TYPO3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/EditorsTutorial/AccessControl/Login/Index.html).

My TYPO3version is 8.7.22.
However, these steps give me a blank page. In

> Templates -> Includes -> ...

...I tried to add the `fluid_content_style`, but it does not work.
Could you suggest some solution or any other tutorial that can be helpful?

Comment: Rather refer to a tutorial, try to debug your code and share your code here and experience here.

Comment: New users are welcome, to take the time and scroll through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In the end, it is a time saver for everybody, better question faster answer increased productivity and better results.

Comment: Thank you all. I did go through the tutorial and followed the steps as per it. I got the reason for the blank page. The setup.ts should have the following for the form to work:page.10 =< styles.content.get. It works fine now.